# Malformed entry error while trying to install Google Cloud SDK

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, debian, debian-buster

When I execute the below command in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install Google-cloud-SDK
```

I am getting the below error.

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Check this answer: [How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score 9):

Remove the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` and re-try the gcloud installation steps solved the problem for my case.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same error when trying to follow the [Install the latest Cloud Tools version for Ubuntu](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb). My problem was that I assumed Google wanted me to add this command to my `.bashrc` instead of just running it in my terminal.

```
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
```

This means running the next step:

```
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

Will result in a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` that reads as (note the double space):

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt  main
```

To fix this, just restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

Use your favorite text editor and fix the entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`:

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt  main
```

The missing part is between that "apt" and "main".  It should be one of the values from Google's [distro list](https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists).  Normally, this can be generated by running `echo cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)`.

A possible valid entry might look like this:

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-zesty main
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment that reads **Normally, this can be generated by running `echo cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)`**